# Confused about the second Function

Tags: python, function

I'm confused about my code, I think I did everything right but I'm not sure how to get the second part of my code to work, the "total_costs" function. I've watched a lot of videos now but can't seem to find one about this, could someone explain to me why I can't get the second part of my code to work?

```
def get_input():
    e1 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for House Payment. "))
    e2 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Homeowners Insurance. "))
    e3 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Payments. "))
    e4 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Insurance. "))
    e5 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Utilities. "))
    print("The monthly expenses total to",format(monthly, ',.2f'))
    print("The yearly expenses total to",format(yearly, ',.2f'))
    

def total_costs():
    monthly = e1 + e2 + e3 + e4 + e5
    yearly = monthly * 12
    return monthly, yearly
    
    

get_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code. First, you're not calling `total_costs()`, so it never gets executed. You're also not capturing the result.

Let's rearrange things:

```
def get_input():
    e1 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for House Payment. "))
    e2 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Homeowners Insurance. "))
    e3 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Payments. "))
    e4 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Insurance. "))
    e5 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Utilities. "))
    monthly, yearly = total_costs()
    print("The monthly expenses total to",format(monthly, ',.2f'))
    print("The yearly expenses total to",format(yearly, ',.2f'))

def total_costs():
    monthly = e1 + e2 + e3 + e4 + e5
    yearly = monthly * 12
    return monthly, yearly
    
get_input()
```

Better, but when you try, it will complain about not knowing about e1. That's because although it might seem that way, total_costs doesn't know about `e1` and other variables. You need to explicitly pass it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def get_input():
    e1 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for House Payment. "))
    e2 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Homeowners Insurance. "))
    e3 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Payments. "))
    e4 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Insurance. "))
    e5 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Utilities. "))
    monthly, yearly = total_costs(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5)
    print("The monthly expenses total to",format(monthly, ',.2f'))
    print("The yearly expenses total to",format(yearly, ',.2f'))

def total_costs(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5):
    monthly = e1 + e2 + e3 + e4 + e5
    yearly = monthly * 12
    return monthly, yearly
    
get_input()
```

Now it all works like you would expect it to work. Now you wouldn't necessarily structure your code like this. For instance it doesn't feel like what you do in `get_input` would require its own function, and maybe instead having all these single variables like `e1`, you could have a structure like a list or a dictionary that you would pass to `total_costs`, but you'll learn that soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is nowhere that `total_costs` is called.

Comment: what do you mean? how do I call it? sorry I'm still pretty new to coding

Comment: ok so get_input() will work because you have called the get_input function. I can't see anywhere in your code that total_costs is called by total_costs()

Comment: @LastCheck I count 15 function calls in your code, so you do know how to do it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the terms for some things, I didn't know the bottom of what I typed was considered a call

Comment: if you want to use monthly and yearly in total_costs after get_input() then get_input must 'return monthly,yearly' at the end of function get_input().

Comment: so where should I call the total_costs function?

Comment: then you would assign that return to monthly, yearly in your main scope, "monthly, yearly = get_input()" then call " total_costs(monthly,yearly)"

Comment: the monthly, yearly variables are local to each function and so are different.  This can be checked by "print( id(monthly), id(yearly))" in different places to get an idea of what scope and namespace mean.

Answer (score 0):

You are using e1,e2,e3,e4,e5 as function variables so the scope is limited to `get_input` function only, you can not use those variables outside `get_input` function until you specify them globaly.

Moreover you are not calling `total_cost` function.

The problem is you are using variables in local scope and not invoking the function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `total_costs()` is not called. If it was not called, how can you expect it to get executed?

And, secondly, *even* if you call `total_costs`, it still will give a `NameError: name 'e1' is not defined`. That's because the variables in `get_input()` are local variables, and thus are deleted when the `get_input()` function is ended.
Therefore, you need to either return the variables from `get_input()`, or use `global` keyword to make them not limited to `get_input()`, though I highly recommend that you use the first method, because `global` makes debugging a nightmare.

Code:

```py
def get_input():
    e1 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for House Payment. "))
    e2 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Homeowners Insurance. "))
    e3 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Payments. "))
    e4 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Insurance. "))
    e5 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Utilities. "))
    print("The monthly expenses total to",format(monthly, ',.2f'))
    print("The yearly expenses total to",format(yearly, ',.2f'))
    return e1,e2,e3,e4,e5

def total_costs():
    monthly = e1 + e2 + e3 + e4 + e5
    yearly = monthly * 12
    return monthly, yearly

get_input()
total_costs()
```

### OR

```py
def get_input():
    global e1,e2,e3,e4,e5
    e1 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for House Payment. "))
    e2 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Homeowners Insurance. "))
    e3 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Payments. "))
    e4 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Car Insurance. "))
    e5 = float(input("What is the monthly expense for Utilities. "))
    print("The monthly expenses total to",format(monthly, ',.2f'))
    print("The yearly expenses total to",format(yearly, ',.2f'))

def total_costs():
    monthly = e1 + e2 + e3 + e4 + e5
    yearly = monthly * 12
    return monthly, yearly

get_input()
total_costs()
```